# How do I add items in Primary Links automatically as soon as some user publish new content

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am building a website www.etutornetwork.com, in top menu I have included a link to a new content type [services]. I want to add a link in dropdown menu as soon as I publish new content in services.

Please Help, Thanks in advance.

and one more question, I dont want to give any name to one of the menu in the site. I tried using or leaving it blank, but it does'nt like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take away the permission from users dealing with menus. Then when you are publishing submitted content from them, you can assign them a menu entry and control the title.

Other than that, you could use Views (since Services is a content type) to create a block that lists all Services with links directly to the node.

Either way, someone will have to title the nodes/menu items. It's easier administrative wise to remove menu permissions from users submitting content.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach it in node creation time (see Menu fieldset), or use module like [Auto Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/automenu). Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> The Auto Menu module automatically generates menu entries on node creation/edition. Parent menu item can be specified on a per content type basis.
>
> This module acts when the menu section of a node is left empty only. So, users can still organize menus manually. Moreover, default setting for content types is to not create menu items automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu), to create my secondary menu. It is very flexible to use. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Features
>
> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
> - Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules